# Counting the number of linear spanning trees in a given undirected graph

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

While solving a question of one of the online coding sites, I encountered this problem.
Is there any algorithm to find the number of linear spanning trees in a given undirected graph such that each node in the spanning tree has atmost one child?

Comment: What did you find/try so far ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "linear spanning tree?"

Comment: A linear spanning tree starts with any node of the graph and each node of the spanning tree has atmost one child i.e the spanning tree is like a line connecting nodes in the graph starting with some node.

Comment: @Spook From briefly looking at a few of those results, none of them seem to cover **linear** spanning trees.

Comment: It might be possible to modify [a Modular Decomposition algorithm](http://www.cs.uoi.gr/~charis/files/SpanTrees-MD.pdf) (unread) to work for linear spanning trees.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question i think it is just asking to find the number of single line nodes. By single line i mean if the graph is

```
      o
     /
o-o-o-o
   \   \
    o-o-o
```

so one of the linear spanning tree will be :

```
      o
     /
o-o-o
```

And to find such trees you can use dfs.

Comment: suppose that there exist an undirected graph with four vertices say 1,2,3,4 sucha that 1 is connected to 2,3,4 and 2 is connected to 3,4 then a linear spanning tree can be 1-2-3-4 or 1-4-2-3 or 1-3-2-4 or 4-2-3-1 or 4-2-1-3

Comment: how 1-2-3-4 can be a solution if 3 and 4 are not connected?

Comment: The example in the answer is not a **spanning** tree (a spanning tree must include all nodes). The only linear spanning tree would be: start at the top node, go clock-wise around and end at the left. And if there are thousands such trees, it could take a while to calculate - we just need the number of such trees. A mathematical equation for this may exist.

Comment: @Dukeling exactly...there is a mathematical formula for that...but i am not able to derive that.